# Differentiate (sin(x))/x using definition of a derivative / first principles?

Tags: calculus

Hello I have a question I have had soem difficulty with for a long time with no answer I could find. How do you differentiate the sine of x divided by x using first principles? I know to use sin(x+h) =sinxcosh + sinhcosx but I am stuck beyond that

Comment: You don't need to use the formula for $\sin(x+h)$. Proceed as usual and note that the limit with respect to $h$ is in the $\frac{0}{0}$ form, so you'll need to use the L'Hôpital's rule(differentiate numerator and denominator with respect to $h$).

Comment: You “just” copy the (known) proof of the quotient rule, substitute the general functions there with your concrete functions here, and repeat the (known) proof of $\sin'=\cos$ where needed. But it's going to be a terrible mess.

Answer (score 1):

When we apply the definition of the derivative and replace $x$ with $x+h$

\begin{align}f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x+h)}{x+h}-\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}{h}\\&
\end{align}

we immediately notice that taking the limit as $h\to0$ would produce the indeterminate form of $\frac{0}{0}$. Hence, we should apply L'Hôpital's rule and differentiate with respect to $h$ to form

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)\cos(x+h)-\sin(x+h)}{(x+h)^2}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x\cos(x+h)+h\cos(x+h)-\sin(x+h)}{x^2+2xh+h^2}$$

which upon taking the limit as $h\to0$ will form

$$\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}$$

Comment: I know how to begin the question and I already have that down. It's how to go on that I can't figure out because no matter how I simplify I can finish it off and get the answer I got using the quotient rule